# Помогите устранить ошибку Bad value for attribute rel on element a

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, валидация

Имеется список переключающихся ссылок с трансляцией `youtube`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.video li:eq(1) a:eq(0)").addClass("on");
  $("ul.video li:eq(1) a").click(function() {
    $("ul.video li:eq(1) a").removeClass("on");
    $(this).addClass("on");
    $("iframe.youtube").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + $(this).attr("rel"));
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="cols video">
  <li>
    <iframe class="youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sU17tLEDfmk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="videos">
      <div class="container scrollbar-inner">
        <a href="#sU19tLEDfmk" rel="sU19tLEDfmk"><span class="title">Прямая трансляция</span></a>
        ....
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Все работает нормально, однако получаю [ошибку валидации](https://validator.w3.org)

> Error: Bad value *sU17tLEDfmk* for attribute **rel** on element **a**: The
>   string *sU17tLEDfmk* is not a registered keyword.

Не подскажите, как в данном случае ее лучше устранить не потеряв при этом функционал?

Comment: Ну, потому что в rel нельзя писать всякую абракадабру - для этого атрибута есть вполне определённые значения: http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/rel Зачем Вам здесь вообще rel? Используйте любой другой атрибут, хоть data-link="sU17tLEDfmk" например (как угодно можно назвать)

Comment: @humster_spb мне для работы скрипта. если я добавлю `data-link="sU17tLEDfmk"` то, ничего в таком виде работать не будет. Вот и интересуюсь, как именно исправить, чтобы работало, а не почему возникает ошибка

Comment: а Вы не понимаете, как работает скрипт? Вот здесь $(this).attr("rel")); измените rel на data-link

Comment: @humster_spb понимаю, но если я хочу оставить `rel` ?

Comment: Ещё раз: в rel НЕЛЬЗЯ писать ничего, кроме специально установленных значений для этого атрибута. Если Вы оставите rel="sU17tLEDfmk", у Вас будет ошибка валидации.

Comment: @humster_spb ок, спасибо

Comment: Помог Ваш вариант. Спасибо!!!!